# Calling Async methods from ActionResults

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ActionResult` method that uploads a file and calls the `CSVReader();` method which reads the file and writes it to a database. However, when the code runs I get an error regarding the `ActionResult` method not being async. Here is my code: (There is a lot)

```
public class files
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public string part_number { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string quote_number { get; set; }
    public string customer_po { get; set; }
    public string order_date { get; set; }
    //public string count { get; set; }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)

    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(("C:\\Dev\\ProductionOrderWebApp\\Uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            CSVReader(fileName);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public static async void CSVReader(string fileName)
    {

        StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);

        DataTable oDataTable = null;
        int RowCount = 0;
        string[] ColumnNames = null;
        string[] oStreamDataValues = null;
        //using while loop read the stream data till end
        while (!oStreamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String oStreamRowData = oStreamReader.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (oStreamRowData.Length > 0)
            {
                oStreamDataValues = oStreamRowData.Split(',');
                //Bcoz the first row contains column names, we will poluate 
                //the column name by
                //reading the first row and RowCount-0 will be true only once
                if (RowCount == 0)
                {
                    RowCount = 1;
                    ColumnNames = oStreamRowData.Split(',');
                    oDataTable = new DataTable();

                    //using foreach looping through all the column names
                    foreach (string csvcolumn in ColumnNames)
                    {
                        DataColumn oDataColumn = new DataColumn(csvcolumn.ToUpper(), typeof(string));

                        //setting the default value of empty.string to newly created column
                        oDataColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

                        //adding the newly created column to the table
                        oDataTable.Columns.Add(oDataColumn);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //creates a new DataRow with the same schema as of the oDataTable            
                    DataRow oDataRow = oDataTable.NewRow();

                    //using foreach looping through all the column names
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        oDataRow[ColumnNames[i]] = oStreamDataValues[i] == null ? string.Empty : oStreamDataValues[i].ToString();
                    }

                    //adding the newly created row with data to the oDataTable       
                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(oDataRow);
                }
            }
        }
        //close the oStreamReader object
        oStreamReader.Close();
        //release all the resources used by the oStreamReader object
        oStreamReader.Dispose();

        //Looping through all the rows in the Datatable
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow oDataRow in oDataTable.Rows)

        {
            Upload vtx = new Upload();
            files csv = new files();
            csv.product_name = oDataRow[0].ToString();
            csv.part_number = oDataRow[1].ToString();
            csv.quantity = oDataRow[2].ToString();
            csv.customer = oDataRow[3].ToString();
            csv.reference = oDataRow[4].ToString();
            csv.contact = oDataRow[5].ToString();
            csv.quote_number = oDataRow[6].ToString();
            csv.customer_po = oDataRow[7].ToString();
            csv.order_date = oDataRow[8].ToString();
            //csv.count = Convert.ToString(count);

            await vtx.VIGL.InsertOneAsync(csv);
            //count++;

            string RowValues = string.Empty;

            //Looping through all the columns in a row
            //var count = 1;
            foreach (string csvcolumn in ColumnNames)

            {

            }
        }
    }

    public class Upload //Constructor
    {
        public IMongoDatabase db;
        internal Upload()
        {

            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();//insert connection string in brackets
            this.db = client.GetDatabase("POWA");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<files>("Imported");
        }

        internal IMongoCollection<files> VIGL          // Good idea to expose all collections as properties
        {
            get
            {


                return db.GetCollection<files>("Imported");
            }
        }

    }



    public ActionResult FileDisplay()
    {
        return View();
    }


}
```

I've gotten it to work outside of MVC (Console) but the `ActionResult`  throws an async error. How do I call the `CSVReader();` method without throwing the error?

Comment: Never ever use async void! http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best for you to use async/await down the whole call stack which is possible with MVC. Mark your Action as async and then use the await keyword to wait for the results from the CsvReader method.

```
// changed signature to async and Task<ActionResult>
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(("C:\\Dev\\ProductionOrderWebApp\\Uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        // add await
        await CSVReader(fileName);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// did not check the code in the method but the signature should return type Task
public static async Task CSVReader(string fileName) {/*existing/unchanged code*/}
```

---

#### Side note

Really the best thing for you to do is to do a little reading on the async/await pattern so you are not just copy/pasting without understanding what is actually going on and why you are using it. It will also help you troubleshoot/debug possible issues later on.

Comment: What should go in the "{some code}" and where should that line be?

Comment: @Evan - You have an existing method called `CSVReader`, the only thing I changed was the signature of the method and so no benifit to copy/pasting the entire method body in the answer again. To make sure that this was somewhat obvious I did include the open/close brackets with a comment in there. I revised the comment.